# Default save location for different OS

Tags: linux, windows, mac

I am making a web application that needs to save files on the client machine. The problem is that the client can be using different types of machines/OSes. I need to hard code (I think) a pathway to a dir on the client's machine because there will be times when my application needs to retrieve those files.

So simply put, is there a universal directory that could be reached on linux, unix and windows systems?

NOTE: This application is to be run by clients within my company only so there shouldn't be any security concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing.  The O/Ses each handle filesystems differently, so I don't believe it'd be feasible or possible.  However, depending on your coding language, I'd imagine you should be able to use the User-Agent from the HTTP header from the browser to determine the O/S it's from, and then use a select/switch/if block to set a string value to a folder appropriate for that O/S, and then use that variable to read/write the file.

Comment: Yeah I believe you are correct. Thought the same thing myself when I posted this question, but wanted to make sure. Will be using one central location for the application. Thanks